# Codeigniter extend library NOT working. No reason

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function My_Form_validation()
    {
        parent::CI_Form_validation();
    }

}
```

This is the code in the file MY_Form_validation.php that I have created in my CI libraries folder. There were some functions in there but i removed them to try and get to the bottom of this.

Utilizing this library extension, form validation simply does not work at all. I have all my form validation rules in a config file.

If i delete MY_Form_validation.php everything works perfectly.

A post on the CodeIgniter board yielded no results.

Perhaps someone here could help?
Thanks

Comment: Nope. The pages load fine but all my if(formvalidated) queries are coming back false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead. You need to pass the $config array from the extended class to the CI_Form_validation. Also make sure the spelling is correct and case sensitive.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function MY_Form_validation( $config = array() )
    {
        parent::CI_Form_validation($config);
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant - Using that, the normal validation rules work. I have not had a chance to implement my custom functions yet, but I imagine they will work. Could you elaborate on as to why this $config var needs to be passed? Is this documented anywhere? On the CodeIgniter forums I was informed by an established member that they used the same code as MINE and it worked. So I have a resolution, but dont really understand it.. Cheers

Comment: The CI loader class of checks for a corresponding config file when it is loading libraries. This happens _ci_init_class() in CI_Loader. The $config array defined in system/application/config/form_validation.php is passed to the extended class, NOT to CI_Form_validation. So this is why you will have to pass it from your extended class yourself to CI_Form_validation in the constructor - you can set new rules here too. Hope this helps you a bit :)

Answer (score 3):

In case you've upgraded to CodeIgniter 2.0.x or later make sure that you change the above code to:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

function MY_Form_validation( $config = array() )
{
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

Notice the change from:

`parent::CI_Form_validation($config);`

To:

`parent::__construct($config);`

Definitely caused me a problem for a bit!

Answer (score 1):

Make file name in your application/library directory:
**MY_Form_validation.php**

then in your class

Code:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation

{
 function My_Form_validation()
   {
       parent::CI_Form_validation();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm using CI 3 Form validation, the following is working for me.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct( $rules = array() )
    {
        parent::__construct($rules);
    }

    //other validation functions...
}
```

Happy Coding